# Shemona Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yaakov was 108 when the sale of Yosef took place:

130 when he came after 2 years of famine

-2 years of famine

-7 years of sava

-13 years between the Yosef's sale and his audience with Paroah

=108

Answer (score 1):

According to http://books.google.com/books?id=tlCHQ6LU988C&pg=PA105&dq=jerusalem, the area of Jerusalem circa 1979 was 108 dunams.

Comment: I think you mean 108 km^2 or 108,000 dunams. (Compare with 125,156 dunams today.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunam http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem

Comment: @Isaac, yes, I do.  :-)